# Unable to import dataset in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: dataset

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sal=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\USER\Downloads\DATASET\Salaries.csv')
```

It shows the following error.

```
File "<ipython-input-11-0befce062f4c>", line 1
    sal=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\USER\Downloads\DATASET\Salaries.csv')
                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How to overcome this type of error.

Comment: try `sal=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\DATASET\Salaries.csv')`

Comment: Sorry,still it shows error.